# Pulling large JSON strings

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest

I have a rest api server which is connected to a Sql database. The database contains large strings which are basically paragraphs that my web app will pull from the server. I will use javascript and Ajax to dynamically change the web app content based on users activity. How should i go about formatting those large string so that i can insert them as paragraphs into HTML? I need a genral advice how can i get this done in JavaScirpt

Let's say i recievie this from my server:

```
{ "name":"Par1",  "content":"Morbi at laoreet ex. Duis porta, felis quis 
pretium semper, est tortor vulputate lorem, ut congue lacus sem vitae 
nisi. Proin at metus porttitor, tempor massa sed, molestie quam. Duis et 
commodo lacus, a lacinia sapien. Nulla tempor non leo a egestas. Curabitur 
imperdiet lectus venenatis neque porttitor, vitae rhoncus dui auctor. 
Nullam scelerisque vehicula massa. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante 
ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec eu viverra tellus, vel ullamcorper neque. 
Duis id orci at turpis lacinia pretium. Sed quis placerat lectus, nec 
viverra urna. Vestibulum dolor enim, mattis sit amet iaculis non, pretium 
consequat neque. Vestibulum rhoncus nisi volutpat lacinia blandit. Aenean 
mollis quis ante a tristique."}
```

then i parse it with JS:

```
var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
```

I extract the paragraph body:

```
var par = returnedData.content
```

What should I do next to format this string so that using jQuery I can insert it into a web page?

Comment: Are you asking about how to break up the string in `content` into paragraphs? Or just how to take the entire string in `content` and put it inside a `p` tag that you append to a `div` or something somewhere on your page?

Comment: I am asking about how to break up the string into paragraphs

Comment: That depends on what you want to consider a paragraph to be. Since the strings don't appear to have any line breaks encoded within them, the best you can do is make crude guesses.

Comment: To add to what @kshetline said, taking an arbitrary string of multiple sentences and breaking it up into "paragraphs" is an impossible task. A paragraph is something a _human_ creates, using one or more sentences to create a unified and coherent thought. So what is it you really want to do: do you want to just take the entire `content` string and format it as one paragraph? (If that's the case, you really don't need to do any formatting at all, just stuff the string into a `<p>` element.) Or do you want to do something other than that?

Comment: On what basis you want to break that `content` string into paragraphs ? Entire string you can put in paragraph : https://jsfiddle.net/eu3bcz07/